# How can I make a timer on the backend that is unique to every user which can be cleared using socketio events

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, settimeout, backend

I am making a turn based multiplayer game using the MERN stack and SocketIO. I want each player to have 60 seconds to play their turn before the game kicks them out. Once that player plays I want the timer to be canceled. I have tried creating a setTimeout function for each player in the game and then using clearTimeout to cancel the timer based on socketIO events, but the timers don't actually get canceled. It could be an implementation problem, so I was wondering what is the best way to implement this functionality? Here's my current implementation:

```
socket.on('Start Countdown', () => {
    let user = getUser(socket.id);
    user.countDown = setTimeout(() => {
      socket.emit('Error', { error: { msg: 'You took too long' } });
      socket.emit('AFK');
    }, 60000);
  });
  socket.on('Stop Countdown', () => {
    let user = getUser(socket.id);
    if (user.countDown) {
      clearTimeout(user.countDown);
      console.log(user.countDown);
    }
    console.log(user.countDown);
  });
```

As mentioned earlier, when "Stop Countdown" happens, the timer doesn't get canceled.
Note: getUser returns a js object, user, of the form {socketId, userId, roomId, countDown} from a users array based on the provided socket.id. There will be no two elements in that array with the same userId and upon refresh, the socketId element will get updated to the correct socket.id. So you can assume that getUser will return the same user object every time, even after refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Guess that should work, but you can try defining a new empty object where its ID is the client.id, so you assign it with the setTimeout value, from there you can check if there is a timer already running for that user or cancel it at the end.

```js
const timers = {};

socket.on('Start Countdown', () => {
    if (typeof timers[socket.id] !== 'undefined') {
        clearTimeout(timers[socket.id]);
    }

    timers[socket.id] = setTimeout(() => {
        socket.emit('Error', { error: { msg: 'You took too long' } });
        socket.emit('AFK');
    }, 60000);
});

socket.on('Stop Countdown', () => {
    if (typeof timers[socket.id] !== 'undefined') {
        clearTimeout(timers[socket.id]);
        delete timers[socket.id];
    }
});
```

Hope that helps you!

Comment: The problem I see with this is that whenever the user refreshes, a new socket.id would be given and a new timer would start. This would mean that the user could keep refreshing and getting a new timer. The getUser function I created returns a specific js object that contains the userid, roomid, countdown function, and socket.id. Whenever the user refreshes, the socket.id changes for that specific object so it can be found using the socket.id later. I tried doing it this way, but it did not work.

Comment: This was a brief example, you could make a class from it and with that class manage the actual user and its timer. 

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `getUser` works, but if fetching from a database the `user` var is destroyed when the `Start Countdown` event ends, you can try to define an object and assign some unique property of the user such as the `id` or the `username` as the key and the timeout as the value:

```js
var timeouts = {} //this must go outside the socket connection event

socket.on('Start Countdown', () => {
    let user = getUser(socket.id);
    //it could be user.id, user.username or some property of user that is unique and unvariable
    timeouts[user.userId] = setTimeout(() => {
      socket.emit('Error', { error: { msg: 'You took too long' } });
      socket.emit('AFK');
    }, 60000);
  });
  socket.on('Stop Countdown', () => {
    let user = getUser(socket.id);
    if (timeouts[user.userId]) {
      clearTimeout(timeouts[user.userId]);
      console.log(timeouts[user.userId]);
    }
    console.log(timeouts[user.userId]);
  });
```

Comment: The reason why I used getUser was because if the user refreshes, there will be a new socket.id. getUser(socket.id) will return a js object with the correct mongodb objectId of the user, the roomId, and the countdown function no matter what the socket.id is. From what I understand from your code, whenever the user refreshes, the socket will get a new socket.id and thus begin a new countdown, but I don't want that to happen because then the user can just keep refreshing and restarting the countdown. Let me know if my interpretation was wrong and if there is a way to solve this issue.

Comment: You are right, the socket.id sould not be the key in this case. So you can continue using getUser(socket.id) but there must be something unique inside `user` that you can use as the key. i'll edit the answer with the code